# How to analytically estimate the pressure loss through an liquid injector?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, airflow

The simple orifice and a pipe have well-documented pressure loss calculation.

But when an injector has complicated flow patterns, is it possible to break it down into simpler sections by which the pressure loss can be calculated?

Or are there procedures to estimate the injector pressure loss?

Or is empirical the only way to measure the pressure loss?

Comment: There may be some empirical correlations, but I would guess you need to test it. Thermodynamically, you can model the injector in three sections: inlet with mechanical pressure, suction region where energy is isenthalpically converted to kinetic energy (high velocity), and expansion region where energy is converted back to mechanical pressure. You could try calculate the velocity in each section and combine that with the geometry to calculate losses with Darcy-Weisbach. But my guess is that you won't capture the elbow/tee conditions well. Maybe close enough for bounding the problem?

Comment: This can be a start! I will try!